# How to upload multiple files from local storage to the azure blob storage using .sh file that located in azure webapp

Tags: linux, azure, sh, azure-blob-storage

I need to upload some *.csv files to the azure blob storage from the .sh file which is located in azure linux webapp. is it possible to do that or how I can do it. Can someone give a sample code if it is possible.

Comment: you can add a webjob to that web app and write the file copy logic in that web job

Comment: Yes. But I need to do it via .sh file.

Comment: Which means do you want to use? Azure CLI?

Comment: but my .sh file should store at /home directory. Or is it possible to access Azure cli via Java code. I call my .sh file via Java code.

Comment: Any more questions? Could it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of curse, you can run the shell script in the Java code with **Runtime.getRunTime().exec**, the example code here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RunningSS {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Process p;
  try {
   String[] cmd = { "sh", "/home/adb/Documents/test.sh"};
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); 
   p.waitFor(); 
   BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    p.getInputStream())); 
   String line; 
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
    System.out.println(line);
   } 
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

To upload the file in the shell script, you can use the Azure CLI command or [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10). For example, if you want to upload the files to the Azure Storage File, then the CLI command is [`az storage file upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-file-upload), but if you use CLI, you need to install it first. See [Install the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

I do not recommend the REST API, it's too complex. If you do not mind, you can take a try.

Comment: @kavin_Ab That's good news. If you think it's OK, please accept it as the answer:-)

Comment: @kavin_Ab Did you not see the message? When it works for you, please accept it as the answer. It would help other communities who are searching for it.